# Google Services After Updating

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

Today I was trying to implement an in-app purchase to my app. I was trying to follow the tutorial from google and it was going fine. In the meantime I was updating some of the SDK's. After all these something somewhere went wrong and all of my Java files gave errors regarding com.google.android.gms. Which was already working fine. I tried;

- Cleaning, rebuilding the project.
- Deleting all the things regarding in-app purchase
- Invalidate caches/restart

The error is something like: cannot resolve symbol xxx (adrequest, adview etc)[image: errors]
Lastly, I am using Android Studio 1.2.0 and my dependencies looks like;

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':baseGameUtil')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by basically moving my project to a different location and changing GooglePlayServicesClient with GoogleApiClient wherever possible. Now it compiles and works fine, hopefully this will help some other fella. Also this site kind of explains how to update to the new GoogleApiClient.

[Updating to GoogleApiClient](https://futurestud.io/blog/how-to-update-from-googleplayservicesclient-to-googleapiclient/)